# How to return a value from a Solidity function when using Wagmi useContractWrite

Tags: reactjs, solidity

I want to get the value being returned in a Solidity function while using Wagmi's useContractWrite.

Example Solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.7;
contract Counter {
uint256 count = 0;

function counter(uint256 number) external returns(uint256){
count = count + number;
return count;
}
}
```

Example React / Wagmi code:

```
const { config, error } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        addressOrName: props.address,
        contractInterface: props.interface,
        functionName: "counter",
        args: [1]
    })
    const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, write } = useContractWrite(config)

<button onClick={() => write?.()}>Hit me</button>
```

In this example I would like to call the write function "counter" and return the result "count".

It seems like {data} from useContractWrite only returns the transaction hash.

Is it possible to return "count" without having to call a separate useContractRead call?

Answer (score 1):

After further research I found this answer to a similar issue:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/88122/97587

This suggests it is a Solidity constraint (not Wagmi). Therefore I emitted an event from the contract on function call and used the following to get the data via the transaction hash:

```
const waitForTransaction = useWaitForTransaction({
    hash: data?.hash,
    onSettled(data, error) {
        const response = data ? data.logs[0].count : []
        console.log("Settled", response)
    }
})
```